# how to remove ids but bot one particular id using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I actually want to remove id attribute of all elements in a set,but not the element with particular id value?Please can you people write the jquery code for me?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)** to exclude the elements that you want.

Try,

```
$('set').not('#particularId').removeAttr('id');
```

Or

```
$('set:not("#particularId")').removeAttr('id');
```

Comment: I _love_ that `set selector`.